# TCL: Find first number in list?

Tags: tcl

Using a list, is it possible to find the first value within a list ? (without using the obvious foreach item> $list loop)

eg I have a list {23dsf} { } {2a} {255} {gsd3fs} {fg'dslk23} {...}

I was looking at [lsearch -integer](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.html), but that requires identifying what the number is :(

I need to simply identify the first numeric value, ie 255 (lindex 3)

Comment: Q: Have you considered lsearch -regex?

Comment: What's wrong with foreach?

Comment: foreaach = too slow....

Comment: @paulsm4 oh yea i forgot about regex's (doh!) thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lsearch -regexp` as pointed out in comments.

given the list:

> set lst {{23dsf} { } {2a} {255} {gsd3fs} {fg'dslk23} {...}}

```
lsearch -regexp $lst {^\d+$}
```

or its equivalent

```
lsearch -regexp $lst {^[[:digit:]]+$}
```

Return the index (3) of the first numeric value in the list.

Comment: This won't find negative integers. But it will find 009, which doesn't pass a `string is integer` check.

Comment: @SchelteBron Correct. Both exceptions were not explicitly requested, just answering to the user's provided example.

Comment: Technically correct with the integer check. that regexp method will meet one of my requirements (I'm checking the day of the month, which can have 01, 02,03, etc.. I can also re-refine the regex to only extract integers with something l like ^[1-9]\d_$

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a `foreach` loop, but if you *really* don't want to, well, recursion is just looping in a different dress:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tcl 8.6

proc firstint {lst} {
   if {[llength $lst]} {
      set first [lindex $lst 0]
      if {[string is integer -strict $first]} {
         return $first
      } else {
         tailcall firstint [lrange $lst 1 end]
      }
   }
}

set lst [list {23dsf} { } {2a} {255} {gsd3fs} {fg'dslk23} {...}]
puts [firstint $lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner, using `lmap` to filter out non-integers and then just taking the first element of what's left:

```
(bin) 9 % set lst [list {23dsf} { } {2a} {255} {gsd3fs} {fg'dslk23} {...} 42]
23dsf { } 2a 255 gsd3fs fg'dslk23 ... 42
(bin) 10 % lindex [lmap i $lst {expr {[string is integer -strict $i] ? $i : [continue]}}] 0
255
```